# <Page> was created without expected prop 'data' in Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I have been trying to load data from `+page.server.ts` using the load function

```js
// +page.server.ts
import { GOGO_SERVER_URL } from '$env/static/private'
import type { PageServerLoad } from '../$types.js'

export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({url, fetch}) => {
    const response = await fetch(GOGO_SERVER_URL + url.pathname + url.search)
    const data = await response.json()
    return { 
        props: {
            data 
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from "../$types";

    export let searchData: PageData
    $: console.log(searchData)
</script>

{#if searchData}
    {#each searchData.data as anime}
        <div>
            {anime.animeTitle}
        </div>
    {/each}
{/if}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

I have used similar code in homepage and it works fine. I have tried changing the structure of the return object to no avail. I don't understand what causes this. I am new to svelte and don't know how to debug this, I have been trying this for 2 days can't find any relevant resource to resolve this issue. I tried copy pasting some of the code from homepage but it didn't work either.

Edit: I have console logged the response of the fetch request and the data is received without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

you need `export let data: PageData` instead of `export let searchData` in `+page.svelte`. You could simply do

```js
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({url, fetch}) => {
    const response = await fetch(GOGO_SERVER_URL + url.pathname + url.search)
    const searchData = await response.json()
    return { 
          searchData
    }
}
```

Then in `+page.svelte`, you can have

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let data;
    $: ({ searchData } = data);
</script>

{#if searchData}
    {#each searchData as anime}
        <div>
            {anime.animeTitle}
        </div>
    {/each}
{/if}
```

Comment: Please don't instruct people to do the hackish destructuring of `data`. I see no benefit here. You could just as easily use the fully qualified `data.searchData` in the template. You could also do `$: searchData = data.searchData` of course

Comment: @Zachiah, this is the first time I am hearing that destructuring is a hack. Updated my answer though

Comment: thanks! I wouldn't say "destructuring is a hack", but rather that the way you were doing destructuring 2 times in a row to get svelte's reactivity to work with it and not use undeclared variables was a hack. I think in general you should use `$: searchData = data.searchData` over `let {searchData} = data; $: ({searchData} = data);` if it was really annoying and you had multiple fields you could also just rename the prop locally to something shorter and use the fully qualified path of course `let d; export {d as data};`

Comment: Actually I prefer `$: ({ searchData } = data);`. I think the `let` part is redundant.

Comment: Yeah that's cool. Didn't know that worked.